# Read json, loop through dictionaries and return as a markup in python

Tags: python, html, json, dictionary

So I have the followng json file:

```
{
    "PersonA": {
        "Name": "Woman A",
        "Age": 23,
        "Info": "Likes cats ..."
    },
    "PersonB": {
        "Name": "Man B",
        "Age": 32,
        "Info": "Likes dogs ..."
    }
}
```

My function should return a markup of this json file. But it seems I can't properly loop through it or rather append my markup data.

Here is my code:

```
markup_s = ""
markup_u = ""
with open('data\module.json') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    for outer in json_data:
        markup_s += outer
        for inner in json_data[outer]:
            markup_u += inner, json_data[outer][inner]
        markup_s += markup_u
return markup_s
```

But this solution seems to have trouble with converting the parts I loop through

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
markup_u += inner, json_data[outer][inner]
```

you try to append a tuple to a string, which obviously fails.

to python, `a, b` is the tuple `(a,b)`. It's the comma which makes the tuple, not the parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, this already helped.
I also turned integers to strings for now, because I don't convert them in particular.
Now I just have to get the syntax done, since some stuff is duplicated and I don't have new lines yet.